# Rails routing with the URL hash (window.location.hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to grab the URL's hash value (e.g. the "35" in /posts/show#35) in routes.rb, or in a controller?

I'm under the impression that this is never sent to the server, but I just wanted to be sure.

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is not sent to the server.