# Rails Hash parameter in the URL Rails Routes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to emulate the same behavior as that of gmail where the URL changes depending on what link you clicked for example https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox.

This link shows how to [add a Hash parameter in the URL Rails Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052399/adding-hash-parameter-in-the-url-rails-routes)

Then can use [jquery to modify the URL hash to add the hash parameter when the view is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting)

From my testing the following route `/route#sent` is seen as `/route` in the server

The part of the puzzle that i'm missing how to [route to the corresponding route as the hash parameter is not sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379482/rails-routing-with-the-url-hash-window-location-hash)?

Comment: Server cannot get the url hash as part of _request_ parameters.   
A dirty approach to do that will involve jQuery. On page load, you can check if url has hash. If it is `/route#sent`, you can make request from JS to something like `/route?query=sent`. When this page loads, url won't have hash, and your JS will compose the hash from the url to `/route#sent`.

Answer (score 0):

Part after the hash is mainly for browser. On a loaded page, if the hash changes 1000 times, browser won't request a thing to the server!

Use a JS framework (like Angular/Vue) or jQuery to detect hash changes and load content accordingly!